# Scope of reference capture in lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, pass-by-reference

Would all the local variables defined within the scope of the enclosing function (both as arguments and as local definitions) be accessible from within a nested lambda function with reference capture? This question has been prompted by the compilation error that I get for undeclared identifiers, in the case of the following code (only relevant code reproduced):

```
template<typename T, typename C>
matrix<T,C>::matrix(C const& crC, unsigned short numElems){

    //lambda 
    function<void()> create_matrix = [&] (){

        if(current_index == sz){

            return;
        }

        auto row = make_unique<T[]>(numElems);
        auto count = 0;

        while(count < numElems){

            row[count++] = crC[current_index++];
        }
        objRef.push_back(row);
        create_matrix();
    };

    auto sz = crC.size();
    auto current_index = 0;
    ref_2_cont objRef = impl_matrix;

    create_matrix();
}
```

I get the following compilation errors within the context of the above code:

```
g++ -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp -o main.o
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./code.hpp:85:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'current_index'
        if(current_index == sz){
           ^
./code.hpp:85:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sz'
        if(current_index == sz){
                            ^
./code.hpp:95:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'current_index'
            row[count++] = crC[current_index++];
                               ^
./code.hpp:97:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'objRef'
        objRef.push_back(row);
```

**Addendum**

This code segment has been added to share with the peer group another usage context in which I had used nested lambdas in a manner similar to the usage implied in the original post. In this case however, the code compiled without any errors or warnings.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
void tree<T1,T2>::reLinkNodes(iter_sp2node_cont Itr){

    //lambda defintion

    function<void(iter_sp2node_cont, r_sp2node_cont)> lnk_part_hier = [&] (iter_sp2node_cont Itr, r_sp2node_cont objRef){

        //lambda definition

        function<void(ptrdiff_t)> lnk_one_hier = [&] (ptrdiff_t diff){

              decltype(diff) index; 

              if(0 == diff){

                  (*Itr).get()->mark_as_root();

                  (*Itr).get()->setParent();

                  ++Itr;
                  (*Itr).get()->unmark_as_root();

                  --Itr;

                  auto cpyItr = Itr;

                  Itr = next(Itr);

                  (*cpyItr).get()->setLeftChild(*Itr);
                  (*Itr).get()->setParent(*cpyItr);

                  Itr = next(Itr);

                  (*cpyItr).get()->setRightChild(*Itr);
                  (*Itr).get()->setParent(*cpyItr);

                  Itr = cpyItr;
              }
              else if(1 == diff){

                  auto cpyItr = Itr;
                  index = 0;

                  (*Itr).get()->setParent(objRef[index]);
                  objRef[index].get()->setLeftChild(*Itr);

                  Itr = next(Itr);
                  (*Itr).get()->setParent(objRef[index]);
                  objRef[index].get()->setRightChild(*Itr);

                  Itr = cpyItr;
              }
              else if (diff > 2 && diff < objRef.size()/2){
                    if(diff % 2){
                        index = diff/2;
                    }
                    else{
                            index = diff/2 - 1;
                    }
                    (*Itr).get()->setParent(objRef[index]);
                  }

              if(diff > 0 && diff < objRef.size()/2){
                  {
                        auto idx = diff * 2 + 1;
                        if(idx < objRef.size())
                        {
                            (*Itr).get()->setLeftChild(objRef[idx]);
                            objRef[idx].get()->setParent(*Itr);
                        }

                        else{
                                (*Itr).get()->setLeftChild();
                        }
                        idx = diff * 2 + 2;
                        if(idx < objRef.size())
                        {
                            (*Itr).get()->setRightChild(objRef[idx]);
                            objRef[idx].get()->setParent(*Itr);
                        }
                        else{
                                (*Itr).get()->setRightChild();
                        }
                    }
                }

              return;
        };
        auto diff = distance(objRef.begin(), Itr);
       if(diff == objRef.size()){

            return;
        }
        else{

               lnk_one_hier(diff);

           }
        if(distance(Itr,objRef.end()) >= 2){
        Itr = next(Itr,2);
        lnk_part_hier(Itr,objRef);
        }
        else if(distance(Itr,objRef.end()) == 1){
            (*Itr).get()->setLeftChild();
            (*Itr).get()->setRightChild();

            return;
        }
        else{
                return;
        }

        return;
    };

    auto cpyItr = Itr;

    renameNodes(cpyItr);

    r_sp2node_cont objRef = hierarchy; 

    lnk_part_hier(Itr, objRef);
}
```

The lambda `lnk_one_hier()` accesses and uses variables that are defined within the scope of the enclosing lambda `lnk_part_hier()`.

Comment: Within the body of the lambda, name lookup is performed under (mostly) normal rules. As usual, names must be declared before they can be found. `current_index` is not declared at the point it's first used (inside the lambda), hence the error.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I agree, but there is another code segment that I have written, which I would like to append to the original post. This had been written in a different context, but this code segment, which compiles without any errors or warnings, also makes use of nested lambdas. However, in this case, the code inside the lambda which has been nested the deepest, accesses and uses variables defined within the scope of the enclosing lambda. I would like your thoughts on the same. In fact, I had written the above code segment based on the previous experience.

Comment: As usual, name lookup looks for names in the current scope, then in the enclosing scope and so on, until found. The fact that some of the scopes are bodies of lambda expressions doesn't change that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OK, since the variables under question in my original post were defined within the immediate enclosing scope, why is it that the compiler couldn't find those definitions? Just trying to understand the difference between what actually worked (based on the code reproduced under the section "Addendum") contrasted with the code that didn't work in my original post. I presume the scenarios are similar.

Comment: For the same reason that `{{x=10;} int x;}` doesn't work. Has nothing to do with lambdas, it's simply that names must be declared *before* they can be used.